# How to automatically generate CSVs at given intervals from phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql

How can I do this? Can it be done with cron jobs? If so, where can I read up on how to do this?

I need to dump the data from my database into a CSV file every so many hours. I want the CSV file to be saved into a folder on the server. Is this even possible with MySQL? I'd appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP isn't necessary.  You can schedule a query to run periodically via a cron job and output to CSV using code like the following:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table WHERE whatever='whatever' INTO OUTFILE 'reports/result.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY ‘\\’
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

With the above query stored in a file, the cron command would look like

```
mysql -u username -p password < filewiththequery.sql
```

If you need to dump the whole database in a way that can be re-imported to the database, use `mysqldump` instead.

Comment: That goes in the cron job file?

Comment: If your query is long, store it in a `.sql` file and call the file from the cron command.  A full crontab entry would look like: `0 * * * * mysql -u username -p password < filewiththequery.sql`  assuming it ran at the beginning of every hour.

Comment: OK.  Don't I need to include the table name in my SQL?

Comment: @shummel7845 sorry yes, you need a full SQL statement before `INTO OUTFILE 'filename.csv'` Edited above.

Answer (score 3):

If you have proper server access I suggest `mysqldump` from a cron job.

Read more about [using mysqldump to output a CSV](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-mysqldump-to-save-data-to-csv-files/).

Comment: +1, agree, and mysqldump performs better dumps than mysqladmin and there 're some really nice script already existing to perform nice backups http://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/

Answer (score 0):

make a script with the following in it:

```
select * into outfile '/tmp/data.csv'
```

fields terminated by ',' ecnlosed by '"' 
escaped by'\' 
lines terminated by'\n' 
from table;

to schedule the job
crontab -u username -e

0 24/4 * * * user scriptname

That should give you a dump every 6 hours.

You will need to read up on some scripting language to provide a unique name to your mysql statement each time it is run.

Comment: I want it to overwrite the old job, so if I use your code as is, won't it do that?